# How to extend this operator on Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

This question was asked in my quiz of Functional Analysis and I was unable to prove this assertion.

> Let H be a Hilbert space and let Y be a Banach Space. Show that if $E\subseteq H$ is a vector subspace and if $T\in L(E,Y)$ , then T can be extended into an operator $T' \in L(H,Y)$ such that $||T' || = || T||$.

Attempt: Assume that there exists an operator $T\in L(E,Y)$ then I have to construct an operator $T' \in L(H,Y)$ and || T' ||=||T||.

How can I define such an operator? It will be equal to T  on L(E,Y) but I am not able to define it on L(H,Y).

Can you please help by giving a brief outine?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess $L(E,Y)$ means bounded linear operator from $E$ to $Y$.  First, if $E$ is not closed, can you extend to its closure?  Second, if $E$ is closed, see if the orthogonal projection onto $E$ can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define the operator $T':\overline{E}\rightarrow Y$ by taking limits, that is, if $a_n\rightarrow a \in \overline{E}$ then
$$T'(a)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}T(a_n).$$
You can prove that the operator $T'$ is a well defined operator and that $||T'||=||T||$

**Remark:** This is actually a really good exercise! However if you don't get to a proof don't worry, because this is also a really important result and it's called Bounded Linear Transformation Theorem, or BLT for short, and you can find its proof by simply puting its name on Google).

Finally define the operator $T'':H\rightarrow Y$ as
$$T''(a)=\left\{
\begin{align}
T'(a)&,\text{ if }a \in \overline{E}\\
0 & ,\text{ in other case}
\end{align}\right.
$$

This time it is way easier to prove that this is a well defined operator that has the same norm as the one defined before.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. I am not able to find the Proof Of BLT by Googling. I have tried hard Can you please post the link to proof here?

Comment: You can find a proof in the page 11 of the file in https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/ch5.pdf.

Comment: Thank you very much!